# Which approach should I use to inject 10+ services in Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired, applicationcontext

I am developing Spring mvc application.

I have a controller in which I am injecting more than 10 Services.

I am exposing 10+ url from this controller and at a time I am using `one or two service` objects in each method.

I was thinking of 2 approaches.

1. Directly inject all services using @Autowired.
2. Fetch Service from ApplicationContext at runtime whenever required.

Please suggest me which approach is better or both approach are equal in terms of memory usage and time

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best approach in most cases is to break up the controller into multiple controllers.
Having too many dependencies is a [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) since your controller most likely violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Both using `@Autowired` for many dependencies and using the ApplicationContext to dynamically retrieve the dependency are mediocre solutions in most cases and should be avoided whenever possible. What you should do is break up the controller and then use `@Autowired` (preferably constructor rather than field injection - check out [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/why-i-changed-my-mind-about-field-injection/) for more details) to make Spring inject the dependencies.

In the case you describe you should not be worried about the performance or the memory consumption of your proposed solutions, but the maintanability of the code.

Although dynamic lookup of a dependency from the ApplicationContext will be a little slower that accesing the injected by the container dependency, in almost all cases you we never be able to tell the difference. As I mentioned above, the first concern you must be looking at is code maintanability, not micro-performance/memory issues.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `Code Smell` issue and `Single Responsibility Principle`. I will break my Controller and will try to implement Single Responsibility Priciple.

Comment: I have one question from your answer. As you mentioned that both the approaches are mediocre solutions and should be avoided. By this are you trying to say that I should avoid injection and create objects using `new`?

Comment: I mean that you should avoid injecting 10 dependencies. You should break up the controller and then inject the relevant dependencies using `@Autowired`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I have accepted you answer. Can you please tell me, is there any advantage of using constructor injection over field injection (any standard practice)?

Comment: The advantage of user constructor injection is that the class is more readable (dependencies are immediately visible via the constructor) and more testable (just create the class using the constructor). Also check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks alot. I had thought that it was a waste of time to ask such question of injection. But this small question opened up any new things for me. I really appreciate efforts of people like you who help us understand concepts better.